# KafKa error java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I did Kafka test and it worked. but when I run the program at IDE, I got this error and don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

```
public final class Constants {
    public static final String REDIS_SERVER = "localhost";

    public static final String KAFKA_SERVER = "localhost";

    public static final String KAFKA_ADDR = KAFKA_SERVER + ":9092";

    public static final String KAFKA_TOPICS = "recom1";

}

val Array(brokers, topics) = Array(Constants.KAFKA_ADDR, Constants.KAFKA_TOPICS)

val sparkConf = new 
SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("RealtimeRecommender")

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet

val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers,"auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest")

val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
```

I think the ip and hostname may not map at /etc/hosts, But there is already   127.0.0.1   localhost. Can anyone help me?

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
    at com.ssx.recom.realtime.RealtimeRecommender$.main(RealtimeRecommender.scala:26)
    at com.ssx.recom.realtime.RealtimeRecommender.main(RealtimeRecommender.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem. Just check the zookeeper, because zookeeper hold the  kafka's configuration information,and saved the kafka's hostname. So IP doesn't work!

Comment: IP will work if you configured Kafka to use it. Note: Kafka DStream is deprecated in Spark 2.3+